# Prove that convex subspace of $l_2$ is compact

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, compactness

Prove that the convex subspace of $l_2$ consisting of all sequences $\xi$ such that
$$
 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \xi_n^2 n^2 \le 1
$$
is compact. Have no idea how to proceed, any hints or suggestions?

Comment: I suppose you know it, but you have to show it's closed and relatively compact. There is a nice theorem about characterizing relative compactness in $l^p$ spaces.

Comment: Any sequence has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: @GEdgar: Yes, I know this criterion, but I have no idea how to select the convergent sequence...

Comment: Given any sequence, there is a subsequence such that all coordinates converge.  Then show you have norm convergence, using the fact that the $n$th coordinate is at most $1/n^2$.

Comment: That's what I got: Let $(x^(i))$ be a sequence (of sequences) in the subspace. Then because the $n$-the coordinate is from the compact subspace $[-1/n,1/n]$ we can select for each coordinate a convergent subsequence, and this gives us a subsequence $x^{(i_j)}$. Let $x = (x_1, x_2,\ldots)$ be the sequence of limits of every coordinate sequence, i.e. $x_k^{i_j} \to x_k$ for $j \to \infty$. Then we have to show $|| x^{i_j} - x ||^2 \to 0$, or equivalently $\sum_k (x_k^{i_j} - x_k) \to 0$, but I here I get stuck because I can just bound the summands by $(2/k^2)^2$...

Answer (score 1):

Being closed: $A=\{\xi|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \xi_n^2 n^2 \le 1\}=\cap A_n$, where $A_n=\{\xi|\sum_{k=1}^{n} \xi_k^2 k^2 \le 1\}$. Now define $T:l_2\to\mathbb{R}$, $T\xi=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \xi_k^2 k^2$. It's continuous (it is not linear, but that doesn't matter), so...

Theorem: A set $A$ is relatively compact in $l_p$ if and only if:

1. There exists $(p_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ so that for every $x=(x_1,x_2,...)\in A$ we have $|x_n|\le p_n$
2. For all $\epsilon$ there exists $n_0$ so that for all $x\in A$ series $\sum\limits_{k=n_0+1}^{\infty}|x_k|^p<\epsilon$.

Comment: yes, this yields that the $A_n$'s as preimages of $[-1,1]$ under $T$ are closed.

Comment: Yes, I think rather preimages of $(-\infty,1]$. And then the intersection of closed sets is closed and that's it for this part.

Comment: yes, but because of $\mbox{range}(T) = [0,\infty)$ this is the same as the preimage of $[0,1]$, and also as $[-1,1]$

Comment: You are right. Do you know the theorem about a set being relatively compact in $l_p$? I could write it in my answer if you don't.

Comment: Is your second statement not fullfilled by every absolut convergent series, i.e. if $\sum |x_i| < \infty$ then $y_n := \sum_{i=n}^{\infty} |x_i|$ is a sequence such that $y_n \to 0$? So in particular the series $\sum |x_k|^p$ in any $\ell^p$ space fulfill them.

Comment: No, this is one $n_0$ for all in A. I guess you mean for all in $l_p$ there is a $n_0$ so that this holds and you are right. But here it states that there is one $n_0$ which is valid for all elements in $A$.

Comment: ah ok. So 1. is fullfilled with $p_n = 1/n$ and 2. for given $\varepsilon > 0$ choose $n_0$ such that $1/n_0^2 < \varepsilon$, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

To create notation which is less confusing for the problem at hand, define $x \in l^{2}$ to be a function $x : \mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|x(j)|^{2} < \infty$. Let
$$M=\{ x \in l^{2} : \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|jx(j)|^{2} \le 1\}.$$
If $x \in M$, then $|x(n)|\le 1/n$ for all $n \ge 1$. Suppose $\{ x_{k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}\subset M$. Then $|x_{k}(n)| \le 1/n$ for all $k \ge 1$. So there exists a subsequence $\{ x_{k_{1,j}}\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ such that $y_{1}=\lim_{j} x_{k_{1,j}}(1)$ exists. Next choose $\{ x_{k_{2,j}}\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ which is a subsequence of $\{ x_{k_{1,j}}\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ such that $\lim_{j} x_{k_{2,j}}(2)=y_{2}$ exists. Automatically $\lim_{j}x_{k_{2,j}}(1)=y_{1}$ exists. Continuing, one finds $\{ x_{k_{N,j}}\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ which is a subsequence of $\{ x_{k_{N-1,j}}\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ such that $\lim_{j}x_{k_{N,j}}(n)$ exists for all $1 \le n \le N$. This Cantor diagonalization process leads to the Cantor diagonal sequence $\{ x_{k_{n,n}}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ which has the property that $\lim_{n} x_{k_{n,n}}(j)=y_{j}$ for all $j=1,2,3,\cdots$.

Now we show that $x_{0} : \mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ defined by $x_{0}(j)=y_{j}$ is in $M$ and that $\{ x_{k_{n,n}}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges in $l^{2}$ to $x_{0}$, from which the compactness of $M$ follows. To do this, notice that, for $J \ge 1$,
$$
                       \sum_{j=1}^{J}|jx_{k_{n,n}}(j)|^{2} \le 1.
$$
Taking the limit with respect to $n$ then gives
$$
                  \sum_{j=1}^{J}|jx_{0}(j)|^{2} \le 1.
$$
Because the above holds for all $J$, then $x_{0} \in M$. Because $|x_{k_{n,n}}(j)|\le 1/j$ and $|x_{0}(j)|\le 1/j$ for all $j \ge 1$, and because $\lim_{n}x_{k_{n,n}}(j)=x_{0}(j)$ for all $j \ge 1$, then the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem gives
$$
         \lim_{n} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|x_{k_{n,n}}(j)-x_{0}(j)|^{2} = 0.
$$
Therefore $M$ is compact in $l^{2}$.

Comment: Note that your first paragraph essentially reproves Tychonoff's theorem that a countable product of intervals (or other compact metric spaces) is sequentially compact, and could be replaced by quoting it.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge: I decided on the approach that requires the least background. You don't avoid much with Tychnoff's Theorem because that last part still needs to said.